# tableofcontents with allowframebreaks breaks internal links

Tags: table-of-contents

sorry if this was asked before. After perusing many comments, I cannot find a solution to the following problem:

I have included a table of contents entry in my latex beamer code, and I had to also include `allowframebreaks`, as my TOC is too long for a single page (it's for a *collection* of presentation slides, of which, there are many).

Now, if I try to click on one of the TOC entries to take me directly to a topic, the click misses the page by the number of extra pages required for the TOC---i.e. as spread over consecutive pages via `allowframebreaks`.

I tried to "manually" "fix" this by including `noframenumbering`. I also tried to manually adjust page numbers via `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}` (or +1). Nothing has worked so far.

Is there something I can do to fix this? As it stands, none of the clickable internal links line up properly.

Thanks in advance.

Here is some code to reproduce the problem. Note that commenting out the last subsection (and corresponding frame) makes the TOC short enough to fit on one page---the problem is gone in that instance.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \begin{frame}[plain,allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]
  \Huge\tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{SSection 1}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 1 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 2}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 2 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 3}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 3 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 4}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 4 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 5}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 5 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 6}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 6 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 7}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 7 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\subsection{SSection 8}
\begin{frame}
    SSection 8 Slide Content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  Can you post example code demonstrating it?

Comment: Yes.. I have code.. but I am not sure how to repsond here with it (sorry, I am new to blogs). I tried pasting the code, but I get a message saying there are too many characters---the code is only 45 lines long.

Comment: Your sample code compiles correctly for me and produces links to the right sections.  Note it was necessary run pdflatex 3 times to get the correct links.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it three times, and now it works for me, too! Thanks!

I wasn't aware that Three's The Charm also applied to latex---I thought it stopped at two.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the document three times with `pdflatex`.

- On run 1, the tableofcontents is empty and there is only one frame.  At the end of the run the `.toc` is written.
- On run 2, the toc is typeset, and fills two frames.  At the end of the run a new `.toc` file is written with the corresponding new destinations.
- On run 3, the information it `.toc` is now correct and the typeset links are accurate.

A tool such as `latexmk` will automatically compile the file enough times to get these links correct.